# UWP html после выполнения javaScript

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

При попытке парсинга сайта, возникла проблема, что необходимый контент загружается с помощью JS функции. Т.е. при попытки получить его(нужный контент) через HttpClient обречены на провал. Попытка ковыряния самого скрипта так же ни к чему не привела. Использовать Selenium(и другие WatiN, WebKit) тоже не представляется возможным(ему необходимо System.Drawing). Знаю, что компонент WebView прекрасно выполняет все скрипты, но как из него вытащить html? Или возможно есть другой способ получить html? 
П.С. Первый раз приходиться парсить, по этому много еще не знаю, очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из WebView достать контент можно например так:

```
var content = await webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", 
      new string[]{"document.documentElement.outerHTML;"});
```

при необходимости, с помощью этого метода можно получать и отдельно результат выполнения **JS**